# Simple Screen Capture for Mac OSX

Tags: osx, screenshot

I am looking for a simple screen capture tool for the current Mac OS.

Most apps on the App Store seem to include Video, which is over the top for me.

I would like something which includes:

- Capture Window
- Capture Menu
- Shows Mouse
- Does not capture window shadows

I have Voila at the moment, but I’m finding their support a bit random, and they’re replacing it with another product (Capto) which has more

Comment: Could you please explain what is wrong with the built-in screenshot tools? http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/#mac Thanks!

Comment: The built-in tools do a very good job, and I didn’t realise until I did some more research how much they do. The only thing missing is the ability to capture the mouse and the menu title.

Comment: When you are done researching about them, would you mind editing your question in light of this, or closing it if solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although you may resolve your question with the built in tools, I'm going to go ahead and recommend you try `Captur`

Captur is a simple Menu Bar interface for Mac OS X screen capture command.

Features:

- Screenshot your screen in many ways such as full screen, window, widget, selection etc
- Capture The Cursor (or not!)
- Capture The Shadow (or not!)
- Add Time and/or Date to the filename
- Specify the format (png, jpg, etc)
- Specify the folder where the screenshot is saved

And that's about it! Very simple.

I found this going through [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/) but the developers website is on blogspot and I can't access that rn, so haven't been able to test. But here is the links:

Alternativeto.net: http://alternativeto.net/software/captur/?platform=mac

Blogspot: http://cambhlumbulunk.blogspot.com/p/captur.html

Couple of screenshots from Alternativeto:

In Mac OS X menu bar:

[image]

Screenshot preview with a screenshot of the settings:

[image]